# If $x \in \overline{A}$ and $A \subset X$, $X$ first-countable, then there's a sequence of points in $A$ converging to $x$.

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Supposedly this relies on first-countability of $X$.

Let $x \in \overline{A}$, then by definition there's a neighborhood $U_1$ of $x$ that contains some $x_1 \in A$.  If this is the only neighborhood of $x$ then we're done since we can let the sequence be $x_1, \dots , x_1, \dots$ and for all neighborhoods $U \ni x$, there's natural $N$ such that $n \gt N \implies x_n \in U$, where $x_n$ is the sequence of $x_1$'s.  That is the topological definition of a sequence converging to a point.

So assume there's another neighborhood $U_2'$ of $x$...

This is where I'm lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven’t used first countability. **Start** by using it to say that there is a fmaily $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ of open nbhds of $x$ such that if $V$ is any open nbhd of $x$, then there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $U_n\subseteq U$. In other words, $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a countable local base at $x$.

That still isn’t quite good enough, though: you’ll want a **nested** local base at $x$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $B_n=\bigcap_{k\le n}U_k$, and let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$.

- Show that $B_n\supseteq B_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.
- Show that $\mathscr{B}$ is a countable local base at $x$.
- For each $n\in\Bbb N$ choose $x_n\in A\cap B_n$ (why is this possible?), and show that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$.